# Media Grid Plugin customisation

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to know whether it is possible to load the LC WEB media grid's item to lightbox contents in any div the media grid is inserted into -

for example see image attached. Id like to take a media grid, place it into a page and set it that it doesnt load into a lightbox but into a column (if I have two bootstrap columns for instance) and also auto stretches the div depending on the content height (auto)..

- See http://www.lcweb.it/media-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHQeE.png)

Any help to make a choice on wheher this is possible to test would be awesome

Comment: Further to my post I am talking about inserting Mediaa Grid shortcode into a Wordpress post or page and wanting to disable the lightboxing and rather show and hide the divisions in my page

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box there doesn't appear to be a way to do this. With some ingenuity I believe it's possible (with some custom javascript and CSS.)

The plugin lightbox makes use of two divs to display the content: `mg_full_overlay` and `mg_full_overlay_wrap`. In our CSS we can set these to be hidden always with `display: none!important`.

So far so good. Now to get that content we can add a new `click` event handler to handle grabbing the content from that div and displaying it elsewhere. Since the content in the hidden lightbox div will refresh even though it's hidden we just need to call jQuery's `html()` and `append()` methods.

This seems like a bit of a hack but I think it would work seamlessly.

**EDIT**

I can only point you in a general direction (right or otherwise) at this point as it seems you haven't written any code yet for us to help with, and I figured you were just looking for a strategy for starters.

I'll add however: I don't know what level of comfort you have with WP theme modification/development and writing javascript but you would only need to modify the theme's javascript and css and perhaps your functions.php or wherever you enqueue your scripts and styles. Wordpress core and the plugin would remain unchanged so you needn't worry about a future update to either breaking something.

If you're using an off the shelf theme you expect updates to you can utilize the [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) ability of WP to leave the original theme untouched.

Let me know in the comments if there's anything specific in my answer you have trouble with and I'll update my answer. For example, if you're unsure of how to use those jQuery methods to do what I mentioned (grabbing content on click from a hidden div and placing it in another div) I can provide some code but you might get a better response from others by dividing this question up into chunks of easier to answer problems and posting a question for each.

You also mentioned in your comment added to the question something regarding the ability to change the way the plugin works via the shortcode you place in pages. This too is probably possible without modifying the plugin itself but without seeing the code of the plugin and trying it it's difficult to say. This too might probably be better in its own question thread.

Comment: Thanks for this, i trust its a solid start but would you mind outlaying code and the pages as I am not quite sure procedurally how to make these changes and keep the core and theme with plugin intact?